# Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and half-open intervals thereof: What kind of space?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my bachelor's thesis, I define the following set:

$\mathcal{S} = [-\pi, \pi)^4 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \times {\mathbb{R}^+}^2$

I would love being able to refer to $\mathcal{S}$ as something more specific than a "set". Intuitively, I would think it's some sort of space.

What is the strongest kind of space that $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies?

Comment: Your example is a (quite decent) subset of $\mathbb{R}^{9}$ so you could certainly endow $\mathcal{S}$ with the accompanying subspace topology, thus making it into a space.

Comment: It‘s a metric space too.